# R - merge unequal regular (15 min intervals) and irregular time series within 10 minutes

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, na

**Revised and Updated Posting**

I have two unequal time series that I would like to merge. **x** contains 20,000+ rows while **y** contains less than 5,000 rows. **x** is regularly spaced at 15 minute intervals while **y** is an irregular time series.

I want to combine **x** and **y** based on whether the dates-times in **y** are within 10 minutes of the dates-times in **x**. For those dates-times in **x** and **y** that are the same, then I want the rows to be added using a function that is shown below.

I had written **x** incorrectly previously so I am correcting it below:

```
library(data.table)

dput(x)
x <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1078077600, 1080028800, 1080029700, 
1080030600, 1080031500, 1091220300, 1091221200, 1091222100, 1091223000, 
1091224800, 1091225700, 1091226600, 1091227500, 1091228400), class = 
c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Etc/GMT-6"), V1 = c(1.6, 1.9, 1.9, 2, 2, 
1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 2.6, 2.8, 3.4, 3.8), V2 = c(0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4, 7.8, 3.2, 
4.9, 4.7, 3.4, 17.1, 25.4, 16.9, 30.6)), .Names = c("Date", "V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")


#      Date               V1 V2 V3   V4
# 1  2004-03-01 00:00:00 1.6  0  0  1.5
# 2  2004-03-23 14:00:00 1.9  0  0  2.3
# 3  2004-03-23 14:15:00 1.9  0  0  2.3
# 4  2004-03-23 14:30:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 5  2004-03-23 14:45:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 6  2004-07-31 02:45:00 1.4  0  0  7.8
# 7  2004-07-31 03:00:00 1.4  0  0  3.2
# 8  2004-07-31 03:15:00 1.5  0  0  4.9
# 9  2004-07-31 03:30:00 1.5  0  0  4.7
# 10 2004-07-31 04:00:00 1.6  0  0  3.4
# 11 2004-07-31 04:15:00 2.6  0  0 17.1
# 12 2004-07-31 04:30:00 2.8  0  0 25.4
# 13 2004-07-31 04:45:00 3.4  0  0 16.9
# 14 2004-07-31 05:00:00 3.8  0  0 30.6

dput(y)
y <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1076902200, 1080029700, 1091221800, 
1091224800, 1091226600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
tzone = "Etc/GMT-6"), V1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), V2 = c(40, 42, 0, 0, 0), V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("Date", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000110788>, 
sorted = "Date")

#                   Date V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1: 2004-02-16 09:30:00 NA 40  0 NA
# 2: 2004-03-23 14:15:00 NA 42  0 NA
# 3: 2004-07-31 03:10:00 NA  0  0 NA
# 4: 2004-07-31 04:00:00 NA  0  0 NA
# 5: 2004-07-31 04:30:00 NA  0  0 NA
```

Based off of the answer by BondedDust in [Using `:=` in data.table to sum the values of two columns in R, ignoring NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106645/using-in-data-table-to-sum-the-values-of-two-columns-in-r-ignoring-nas), I wrote a dyadic operator for "+" when the dates-times are the same in **x** and **y**.

```
`%+na%` <- function(x, y) {ifelse(x == 0 & is.na(y) == TRUE, NA, 
 ifelse(x != 0 & is.na(y) == TRUE, x, x+y))}
```

Based on Arun's answer, I have the following code:

```
setkey(setDT(x), Date)
setkey(setDT(y), Date)
xidx = x[y, roll = "nearest", which = TRUE]
yidx = which(abs(x$Date[xidx] - y$Date) <= 600)
xy <- rbind(x, y[yidx, ])
```

This is what xy looks like at this point:

```
dput(xy)
xy <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1078077600, 1080028800, 1080029700, 
1080030600, 1080031500, 1091220300, 1091221200, 1091222100, 1091223000, 
1091224800, 1091225700, 1091226600, 1091227500, 1091228400, 1080029700, 
1091221800, 1091224800, 1091226600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "Etc/GMT-6"), V1 = c(1.6, 1.9, 1.9, 2, 2, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 2.6, 2.8, 3.4, 3.8, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0), V3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(1.5, 
2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4, 7.8, 3.2, 4.9, 4.7, 3.4, 17.1, 25.4, 16.9, 
30.6, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Date", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000200788>)

#                   Date  V1 V2 V3   V4
# 1: 2004-03-01 00:00:00 1.6  0  0  1.5
# 2: 2004-03-23 14:00:00 1.9  0  0  2.3
# 3: 2004-03-23 14:15:00 1.9  0  0  2.3
# 4: 2004-03-23 14:30:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 5: 2004-03-23 14:45:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 6: 2004-07-31 02:45:00 1.4  0  0  7.8
# 7: 2004-07-31 03:00:00 1.4  0  0  3.2
# 8: 2004-07-31 03:15:00 1.5  0  0  4.9
# 9: 2004-07-31 03:30:00 1.5  0  0  4.7
# 10: 2004-07-31 04:00:00 1.6  0  0  3.4
# 11: 2004-07-31 04:15:00 2.6  0  0 17.1
# 12: 2004-07-31 04:30:00 2.8  0  0 25.4
# 13: 2004-07-31 04:45:00 3.4  0  0 16.9
# 14: 2004-07-31 05:00:00 3.8  0  0 30.6
# 15: 2004-03-23 14:15:00  NA 42  0   NA
# 16: 2004-07-31 03:10:00  NA  0  0   NA
# 17: 2004-07-31 04:00:00  NA  0  0   NA
# 18: 2004-07-31 04:30:00  NA  0  0   NA
```

The next line is modified from the solution provided by akrun here: [Identifying duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041933/identifying-duplicated-rows).

```
xy[, lapply(.SD, xy[which(duplicated(xy))] %+na% xy[which(duplicated(xy, 
fromLast = TRUE))]), keyby = Date]
```

Can someone suggest a modification to this last line so that I don't have this error message?:

```
# Note the new error message that I am receiving:
# Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), 
# nrow = nr, : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Thank you in advance.

This is the final, expected result below (it has been changed, see row 8 with the NAs):

```
dput(xy)
xy <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1078077600, 1080028800, 1080029700, 
1080030600, 1080031500, 1091220300, 1091221200, 1091221800, 1091222100, 
1091223000, 1091224800, 1091225700, 1091226600, 1091227500, 1091228400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Etc/GMT-6"), V1 = c(1.6, 
1.9, 1.9, 2, 2, 1.4, 1.4, NA, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 2.6, 2.8, 3.4, 3.8
), V2 = c(0, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V4 = c(1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 
2.4, 2.4, 7.8, 3.2, NA, 4.9, 4.7, 3.4, 17.1, 25.4, 16.9, 30.6
)), .Names = c("Date", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")


#                  Date  V1 V2 V3   V4
# 1  2004-03-01 00:00:00 1.6  0  0  1.5
# 2  2004-03-23 14:00:00 1.9  0  0  2.3
# 3  2004-03-23 14:15:00 1.9 42  0  2.3
# 4  2004-03-23 14:30:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 5  2004-03-23 14:45:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 6  2004-07-31 02:45:00 1.4  0  0  7.8
# 7  2004-07-31 03:00:00 1.4  0  0  3.2
# 8  2004-07-31 03:10:00  NA  0  0   NA  <-- Notice: the change here
# 9  2004-07-31 03:15:00 1.5  0  0  4.9
# 10 2004-07-31 03:30:00 1.5  0  0  4.7
# 11 2004-07-31 04:00:00 1.6  0  0  3.4
# 12 2004-07-31 04:15:00 2.6  0  0 17.1
# 13 2004-07-31 04:30:00 2.8  0  0 25.4
# 14 2004-07-31 04:45:00 3.4  0  0 16.9
# 15 2004-07-31 05:00:00 3.8  0  0 30.6
```

The NA columns in **xy** will be interpolated using na.approx thus the change from the original question posted here.

---

**UPDATED POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

The following section of code is taken from Arun's answer:

```
setkey(setDT(x), Date)
setkey(setDT(y), Date)
xidx = x[y, roll = "nearest", which = TRUE]
yidx = which(abs(x$Date[xidx] - y$Date) <= 600)
xy <- rbind(x, y[yidx, ])
setkey(xy, Date)
```

Both a and b are derived from [Identifying duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041933/identifying-duplicated-rows)

```
a <- which(duplicated(xy, fromLast = TRUE))
b <- which(duplicated(xy))
```

Can someone offer a better way to proceed with the following steps?

```
xyadd <- vector("list", length(a)) # pre-allocate the list since it is   
# being used in a for loop / Sources:
```

[Add a Column to a Dataframe From a List of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130037/add-a-column-to-a-dataframe-from-a-list-of-values/11130178) and [Why does is.vector() return TRUE for list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032772/why-does-is-vector-return-true-for-list/6032909)

```
for(u in seq(a))
{
xyadd[[u]] <- xy[a[u], .SD, .SDcols = 2:5] %+na% xy[b[u], .SD, .SDcols = 2:5]
}

xyadd2 <- data.frame(unlist(xyadd))
xyadd2 <- ifelse(nrow(xyadd2) > prod(length(a)*4), xyadd2 <- 
data.frame(xyadd2[-nrow(xyadd2), ]), xyadd2) 
# 4 comes from the 4 columns that I have
xyadd2 <- xyadd2[1][[1]]
xyadd2 <- matrix(data = xyadd2, nrow = length(a), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
xyadd2 <- as.data.frame(xyadd2)
xyadd2 <- setDT(xyadd2)

xy[a, `:=` (V1 = xyadd2[, V1], V2 = xyadd2[, V2], V3 = xyadd2[, V3], 
V4 = xyadd2[, V4])]
xy <- xy[-b, ]
```

I get the same **xy** as shown above.

I have not posted the potential solution above as an answer because I would like to receive feedback on making the code more efficient. Data set **x** consists of 20,000+ rows while data set **y** consists of less than 5,000 rows. The solution will need to be applied to about 20 file sets.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @David Arenburg  The values in V4 will remain the same in the final data set of xymerge. In xymerge, there should be 15 rows (all 14 rows from x and row 3 from y). The values in x and y are a small subset of some of the actual data sets that I'm using. Some of the 0s became NAs in the new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930548/r-data-table-dyadic-operator-and-summing-duplicate-rows-based-on-time-se). Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` solution

```
A <- expand.grid(y$Date, x$Date) #all possible combination of dates
#indices of y, of which the time diff to x is less than 10 min
ind <- which(abs(A$Var1-A$Var2)<10*60) %% nrow(y)
ind[ind==0] <- nrow(y) 
y1 <- y[ind, ] #dump the obsolete values

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(x, y1) %>%  #alternative to rbind(x,y1)
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))     
#Source: local data frame [15 x 5]
#
#                  Date  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  2004-03-01 00:00:00 1.6  0  0  1.5
#2  2004-03-23 14:00:00 1.9  0  0  2.3
#3  2004-03-23 14:15:00 1.9 42  0  2.3
#4  2004-03-23 14:30:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
#5  2004-03-23 14:45:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
#6  2004-07-31 02:45:00 1.4  0  0  7.8
#7  2004-07-31 03:00:00 1.4  0  0  3.2
#8  2004-07-31 03:10:00 0.0  0  0  0.0
#9  2004-07-31 03:15:00 1.5  0  0  4.9
#10 2004-07-31 03:30:00 1.5  0  0  4.7
#11 2004-07-31 04:00:00 1.6  0  0  3.4
#12 2004-07-31 04:15:00 2.6  0  0 17.1
#13 2004-07-31 04:30:00 2.8  0  0 25.4
#14 2004-07-31 04:45:00 3.4  0  0 16.9
#15 2004-07-31 05:00:00 3.8  0  0 30.6
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I created a `data.table` partial solution based off of your answer. `B <- CJ(x1$Date, y1$Date); 
ind <- CJ(1:nrow(x1),1:ncol(y1))[which(abs(B$V1 - B$V2) < 10*60),]$V2; y2 <- y1[ind, ]; xylist <- list(x1, y2); xy <- rbindlist(xylist, use.names=TRUE); setkey(xy, Date)` I've added NAs to my original data sets so I've asked a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930548/r-data-table-dyadic-operator-and-summing-duplicate-rows-based-on-time-se).

Comment: In the new posting, I would have to keep the NAs rather than remove them because any remaining NAs in the final table will have to be interpolated. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: `summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 2):

using `data.tabe`'s rolling joins:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(x), Date)
setkey(setDT(y), Date)
xidx = x[y, roll="nearest", which=TRUE]
yidx = which(abs(x$Date[xidx] - y$Date) <= 600)
ans = rbind(x, y[yidx]) ## uses faster 'rbind.data.table'
ans[, lapply(.SD, sum), keyby=Date]
```

The way I've approached the problem is as follows:

Get all the indices of `x` by joining to the *nearest* value of `y` using `roll="nearest"` on `Date` column. Then, find those indices in `y` where the nearest matching dates are at most 10 minutes apart. Use that to subset `y` and bind it with `x`, then aggregate.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and explanation. I am receiving an error message with ans.  Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill) : 
Item 2 has 4 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 5 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fill' to TRUE. Based on much of your solution, I have created a working solution below.

Comment: Yes, I get the error on the original example data (without the NAs) using the exact code that you have supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly based on Arun's answer, I have created the following `data.table` solution that works.

```
setkey(setDT(x), Date)
setkey(setDT(y), Date)
xidx = x[y, roll = "nearest", which = TRUE]
yidx = which(abs(x$Date[xidx] - y$Date) <= 600)
xy <- rbind(x, y[yidx, ]) # In this line, I have added the comma after yidx, 
# which is the only difference from Arun's solution.
xy <- xy[, lapply(.SD, sum), keyby = Date]
```

**Update**

Based on Arun's comment, below, I have modified this solution. Thank you Arun.

```
# xy
#                  Date  V1 V2 V3   V4
# 1: 2004-03-01 00:00:00 1.6  0  0  1.5
# 2: 2004-03-23 14:00:00 1.9  0  0  2.3
# 3: 2004-03-23 14:15:00 1.9 42  0  2.3
# 4: 2004-03-23 14:30:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 5: 2004-03-23 14:45:00 2.0  0  0  2.4
# 6: 2004-07-31 02:45:00 1.4  0  0  7.8
# 7: 2004-07-31 03:00:00 1.4  0  0  3.2
# 8: 2004-07-31 03:10:00 0.0  0  0  0.0
# 9: 2004-07-31 03:15:00 1.5  0  0  4.9
# 10: 2004-07-31 03:30:00 1.5  0  0  4.7
# 11: 2004-07-31 04:00:00 1.6  0  0  3.4
# 12: 2004-07-31 04:15:00 2.6  0  0 17.1
# 13: 2004-07-31 04:30:00 2.8  0  0 25.4
# 14: 2004-07-31 04:45:00 3.4  0  0 16.9
# 15: 2004-07-31 05:00:00 3.8  0  0 30.6
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap in a list and use `rbindlist()`. You can use `rbind()` directly, which calls `rbindlist()` underneath... And you don't need to `setkey()` before aggregating.

Comment: @Arun   Thank you for your suggestions. I have revised the answer above based on your feedback.